# Minizip - Using fopen with UTF-8 filenames

Tags: c++, utf-8, unzip, multiplatform

I am in the same situation as [fopen with unicode filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21402742/fopen-with-unicode-filename), where I want to use a library that uses fopen. The library in question is minizip, and I need it to work with UTF-8 encoding, on windows, UNIX (OSX), iOS and Android.
I read the answers, including the discussion about GetShortPathName, and essentially the conclusion is to rewrite the library.
Is there any way around this?
Also, I read that the fopen function on UNIX system can handle UTF-8 encoding (unlike its windows counterpart). Can anyone confirm this?

I would really hate to have to go around and place some ifdef WINDOWS around everywhere in minizip... Does anyone have an alternative?

Answer (score 2):

Under Windows use `_wfopen` for Unicode projects. Note that it accepts Unicode (UTF-16) strings, not UTF-8. For UTF-8 the standard `fopen` has extra option `ccs`: `FILE *fp = fopen("newfile.txt", "rt+, ccs=encoding");`

Comment: From what I understand, the encoding option for fopen applies to the content of the file, not the filename. Am I wrong?

Comment: @DavidMenard Not sure about `ccs` - maybe you are right. `_wfopen` is for Unicode filenames.

Answer (score 0):

The situation is a bit better in nowadays, you should not modify sources of **Minizip**, but still will be required one `#ifdef` in your code for support **Unicode** in file paths in **Windows**. Latest versions has new API functions for read/write ZIP:

- **unzOpen2_64**(const void *path, zlib_filefunc64_def* pzlib_filefunc_def)
- **zipOpen2_64**(const void *pathname, int append, zipcharpc* globalcomment, zlib_filefunc64_def* pzlib_filefunc_def)

The parameter `zlib_filefunc64_def` may refer to structure with set of functions for work with file system (or memory). Additionally, **Minizip** package supplies header file '[iowin32.h](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/contrib/minizip/iowin32.h)' that have methods for fill `zlib_filefunc64_def` structure using **Windows API**. So, for open file for reading you can use code like below:

```
zipFile openZipFile(const std::string& utf8FilePath)
{
    zipFile hZipFile = nullptr;
    #ifdef WIN32
        zlib_filefunc64_def ffunc;
        fill_win32_filefunc64W(&ffunc);

        // Convert path from UTF-8 to Unicode
        const int count = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, utf8FilePath.c_str(), static_cast<int>(utf8FilePath.size()), NULL, 0);
        std::wstring unicodePath(count, 0);
        MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, utf8FilePath.c_str(), static_cast<int>(utf8FilePath.size()), &unicodePath[0], count);

        hZipFile = zipOpen2_64(unicodePath.c_str(), 0, NULL, &ffunc);
    #else
        // Unix systems handles path in the UTF-8 by default
        hZipFile = zipOpen64(utf8FilePath.c_str(), 0);
    #endif

    return hZipFile;
}
```

The second worked option that I've found - just set the locale to **UTF-8**. Better to do it at the application initialization layer, as it's not thread safe:

```
std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_us.utf8");
```

It looks much simpler, but I think that first variant is better and reliable as it doesn't depend to locale settings.