# Extracting file from zip using wide string file path in C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, zip, widechar

How can you read a file from a zip by opening the zip with a wide string file path? I only saw libraries and code examples with `std::string` or `const char *` file paths but I suppose they may fail on Windows with non-ASCII characters. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9717068) but I'm not using `gzip`.

**Attempts**

[`minizip`](https://github.com/zlib-ng/minizip-ng):

```
const auto zip_file = unzOpen(jar_file_path.string().c_str()); // No wide string support
if (zip_file == nullptr)
{
    throw std::runtime_error("unzOpen() failed");
}
```

[`libzippp`](https://github.com/ctabin/libzippp):

```
libzippp::ZipArchive zip_archive(jar_file_path.string()); // No wide string support
const auto file_opened_successfully = zip_archive.open(libzippp::ZipArchive::ReadOnly);
if (!file_opened_successfully)
{
    throw std::runtime_error("Failed to open the archive file");
}
```

[`Zipper`](https://github.com/sebastiandev/zipper/blob/master/zipper/unzipper.h) does not seem to support wide strings either. Is there any way it can currently be done?

Comment: I don't know if this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14628171/260313 (minizip), and https://stackoverflow.com/a/9746912/260313 (zlib).

Answer (score 1):

You might be in luck with minizip.  I haven't tested this, but I found the following code in [mz_strm_os_win32.c](https://github.com/zlib-ng/minizip-ng/blob/master/mz_strm_os_win32.c):

```
int32_t mz_stream_os_open(void *stream, const char *path, int32_t mode) {

...

    path_wide = mz_os_unicode_string_create(path, MZ_ENCODING_UTF8);
    if (path_wide == NULL)
        return MZ_PARAM_ERROR;

#ifdef MZ_WINRT_API
    win32->handle = CreateFile2(path_wide, desired_access, share_mode,
        creation_disposition, NULL);
#else
    win32->handle = CreateFileW(path_wide, desired_access, share_mode, NULL,
        creation_disposition, flags_attribs, NULL);
#endif

    mz_os_unicode_string_delete(&path_wide);

...
```

So it looks very much as if the author catered explicitly for Windows' lack of built-in UTF-8 support for the 'narrow string' file IO functions.  It's worth a try at least, let's just hope that that function actually gets called when you try to open a zip file.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding **Minizip** library, API function `unzOpen()` works well with **UTF-8** only on **Unix** systems, but on **Windows**, path will be processed only in the current **CodePage**. For get full **Unicode** support, need to use new API functions `unzOpen2_64()` and `zipOpen2_64()` that allows to pass structure with set of functions for work with file system. Please see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75055700/5265572) with details in the similar question.